# Capybara::ElementNotFound when testing with rspec

Tags: ruby, rspec, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm working on my rails4 application, following a Rails tutorial. Got a failure when testing my authentication signin page. Error message says:

```
Failure/Error: fill_in "email",    with: user.email.upcase
 Capybara::ElementNotFound:
   Unable to find field "email"
 # ./spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb:35:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Although my session#new.html.erb have such elements:

```
<%= form_for(:session, url: sessions_path) do |f| %>

  <%= f.label :email %>
  <%= f.text_field :email %>

  <%= f.label :password %>
  <%= f.password_field :password %>

  <%= f.submit "Sign in", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

Here is my authentication_pages_spec.rb relative testing part:

```
describe "with valid information" do # signin with valid information
      let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
      before do
        fill_in "email",    with: user.email.upcase
        fill_in "password", with: user.password
        click_button "Sign in"
      end

      it { should have_title(user.name) }
      it { should have_link('Profile',     href: user_path(user)) }
      it { should have_link('Sign out',    href: signout_path) }
      it { should_not have_link('Sign in', href: signin_path) }

      describe "followed by signout" do
        before { click_link "Sign out" }
        it { should have_link('Sign in') }
      end
   end
```

I've tried adding 'visit signin_path' into testing section, still fail with same message.
Could someone help me figure out where i made a mistake, please?  Thanks a lot.

Comment: This error can have a bunch of different reasons, so I will rather give you some hints what to check:

a) capybara usually searches case-sensitive, and fill_in 'email' for a field with label, name or id 'email'. The id of your form field in your case will rather be 'session_email', name 'session[email]' so only the label is left. Per default it would be 'Email' not 'email'.

b) any wrong redirect, error, etc. would cause this error because capybara couldn't find the login form. If you use launchy you can at anytime call save_and_open_page and inspect the page in your browser, this might help.

Comment: Thank you, @trueunlessfalse. I've tried solution a before posted this query, doesnt work as expectation. Sorry but I dont quite get solution b, did u mean that i should add some tag into section '<%= form_for(:session, url: sessions_path) do |f| %>'?

Answer (score 1):

I believe if you move

```
describe "followed by signout" do
before { click_link "Sign out" }
it { should have_link('Sign in') }
end
```

before the `it { should have_title(user.name) }` block it should pass. I had the same issue and that fixed it for me!